# How do I get lightning:datatable to do some undocumented thing X?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, canonical-qa

## Canonical Question

I want to do *<some really cool thing>* with a `lightning:datatable`, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I checked the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable), but I did not see a way to implement *<this really cool feature I need>*.

Perhaps I want to provide tooltips, or a pick list, or alter the behavior of the menus, or display images, or show a custom component I created, or define a new row-level click behavior, or alter the keyboard event handlers, etc.

Can I somehow do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Canonical Answer

Please note: if you have been directed to this question and answer, what you are attempting to do with `lightning:datatable` cannot be done. You will need to find an alternative method, such as using a normal SLDS data table instead.

---

Unfortunately, in the general sense, the features in the documentation are all that you get. It is possible capture bubbled events from the `lightning:datatable` itself and modify its look with custom styles. However, because of [Locker Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_code.htm) security restrictions, you generally cannot modify the component's behavior, DOM, or internal CSS styles. If you do not see a feature mentioned in the official documentation, what you are attempting to do is most likely not possible.

The standard workaround for right now is to write your own SLDS-compatible [data tables](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/data-tables/). Please remember to check the [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/) with each new release to see if a feature you were looking forward to has been released, and also remember to search for and vote on/post an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch) for this feature that you would like to see in a future release.