# Can we add borders to selected row in datatable?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, css, lightning-datatable

How can we add border to a selected row in datatable in lwc?[image: DataTable image with border]

Comment: you need to check if Salesforce add some sort of classes to the whole row when it's selected or add them yourself when handling select event. Afterwards you put styles for this CSS class into Static Resource and load on the page

Comment: When I inspect the row I see this
<tr data-row-key-value="row-1" aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" class="slds-hint-parent"> 
I am not sure how I can add border to it. @ytiq

Comment: See [How do I get lightning:datatable to do some undocumented thing X?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231226/how-do-i-get-lightningdatatable-to-do-some-undocumented-thing-x). Attempts to futz with the internal CSS of a standard component may break at any time in the future.

Comment: ok, there is `rowselection` and you can theoretically dynamically add/remove styles with `"table" tr:nth-child(${row-index}) { ... }`, it's kind of messy but should work